# How to factor a color and boder-color into a single CSS style and apply it on other parts of the CSS styles

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following styles in a **Site.css** which is part of a **ASP.NET MVC4** Site

```
form label.error { font-size: 12px; color: #cc0000; }
form input:not([type="submit"]).error{ border-color: #cc0000; }
form select:not([type="submit"]).error{ border-color: #cc0000; }
.error { color: #cc0000; }
```

I want to know how can I modify that file to be able to change that `#cc0000;` without changing it on every single line (factor out the color used for validation errors in this case)

Something similar to this:

```
errorStyle {
    color: #cc0000 ;
    border-color: #cc0000;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
form label.error { font-size: 12px; errorStyle }
form input:not([type="submit"]).error{ errorStyle }
form select:not([type="submit"]).error{ errorStyle }
.error { errorStyle }
```

In this way if the client wants that color to be changed it easier to maintain.

Comment: Consider using SASS or LESS

Comment: A completely different idea would be to set the `error` class to the `form` when any field has an error and then use `currentColor` for `border-color`. Setting `color` on parent will make the children inherit it and so all that would need to be done is set `color` on parent.

Comment: @Harry could you please post the details of your answer, I am css newbie ;-)

Comment: @Morpheus does that play well with a ASP.NET MVC4 solution ? is there a NuGet package ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez: What I meant is something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dwgjapt6/). I don't know how useful it is for you and so not yet posting an answer. If it helps you then I will.

Comment: @Mauricio Gracia Gutierrez yes, it does. I am using SASS for all the projects and Koala compiler as I was disappointed on how slow Visual Studio extensions are running with multiple projects (like Sassy, Web Essentials). I don't know if there is a nuget package, but you can find it out easily.

Comment: @Harry thanks for that fiddle, the only thing that is not working is the font-size attribute for the "font.error label" I change that to 9px and is still being shown in the default size

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez: It is working for me if I change the `font-size`. Just to sure, did you use the selector as `font.error label` or `form.error label`?

Comment: Form.error it was a typo in the comment, Please post it as answer since is really useful

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez: I had edited in the CSS3 tag also because `currentColor` is a CSS3 keyword. Hope you don't have any concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way of avoiding repetition without using any pre-processors would be to apply the `error` class (the one that contains the `color`) to the `form` element and then make use of `currentColor` to use the same color that was applied to the parent.

The `currentColor` is a keyword that points to existing color that is applied to the element. [Support for this keyword is pretty decent and it works in all major browsers except IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=currentcolor).

For `border-color`, [the default value is always the same as the `color` applied to the element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#currentcolor) (which again is same as the `currentColor`) and hence we could also use `inherit` as the value instead of `currentColor`. The `inherit` basically tells the browser to inherit the parent's border color.

In the below snippet, I've applied `currentColor` for one element and `inherit` for another element to just show how both give same output.

```css
form.error label {
  font-size: 16px;
}
form.error input:not([type="submit"]) {
  color: currentColor;
  border-color: currentColor;
}
form.error select {
  color: inherit;
  border-color: inherit;
}
.error {
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

```html
<form class='error'>
  <label>Hello</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

---

If you want to apply the `error` class to the individual elements also (that is, add red border and color only to the element with error) then that is also possible.

```css
form.error label.error {
  font-size: 16px;
}
form.error input:not([type="submit"]).error {
  border-color: currentColor;
}
form.error select.error {
  border-color: inherit;
}
.error {
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

```html
<form class='error'>
  <label class='error'>Hello</label>
  <input type='text' class='error' />
  <select class='error'>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <input type='text' />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My only concern is that I don't see the line that does this "form select:not([type="submit"]).error{ border-color: #cc0000; }

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez: `select` can never have `type='submit'` (that is only for `input`) and hence I removed that part. The others are present in the snippet (with `border-color` as `currentColor` or as `inherit`).

Comment: Harry - thanks - I have posted the CSS snipped that I ended up using in order to maket it work for font-size (probably other parts of the css that I did not posted interfer somehow) - if you can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)/[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (or [any other css pre-processor](http://www.sitepoint.com/6-current-options-css-preprocessors/)) to enable CSS parameter:

```
@color: #cc0000;

form {
    label.error,
    input:not([type="submit"]).error {
         border-color: @color;
    }
}
```

Without that, you will be stuck with bunch of classes.

```
.hasError {
      border-color: #cc0000;
 }
```

and add this class to any element, that has to have this style. But in the end you will be facing with too much classes. Like `<div class="hasError red transparentBackground bigSize customPointer">`

Comment: Justinas, thanks - does this solutions play well with a ASP.NET MVC4 solution ? is there a NuGet package to use either LESS or SASS ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I haven't used .NET ever, but first search in google for `NuGet Less` resulted in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Less/

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to using a pre-processor like Less or Sass, is to adopt `DRY CSS` layout, which instead of grouping styles by element (as CSS is traditionally written), groups elements by style.

**Example:**

```
.FONT-SIZE,
form label.error {font-size: 12px;}

.COLOR,
.error,
form label.error {color: #cc0000;}

.BORDER-COLOR,
form input:not([type="submit"]).error,
form select:not([type="submit"]).error {border-color: #cc0000;}
```

Comment: Rounin, this looks more organized but I still see the color in two lines (and CSS is likely to grow in the future)

Comment: Yes, if you needed to update the `color` and `border-color`, you'd still have to make two edits (ie. one for each attribute). But only two. DRY CSS is not for everyone. I learned about it and adopted it 3 years ago. Since then, editing and debugging CSS has been a dream compared to what I used to confront when I wrote traditional (_ie. styles-grouped-by-element_) stylesheets before that. And DRY CSS obviates the need for CSS pre-processors.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this snippet based on [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) answer

```
label.error {
  font-size: 11px;
}

form.error input:not([type="submit"]) {
  color: inherit;
  border-color: currentColor;
}

form.error select {
  color: inherit;
  border-color: currentColor;
}

.error {
  color: #cc0000;
}
```